# Flutter build apk error - Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build an android apk, when I run the app or flutter build apk the following error occurs, i'm using flutter 3.0.5.

```
 Building with sound null safety 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/edgar/Documents/tools/flutter-35/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command '/Users/edgar/Documents/tools/flutter-35/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           47,0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: What output does the command "flutter doctor -v" produce for you?

Comment: @jraufeisen print -> https://imgur.com/CPgn3xZ